# Homology of Tori Glued by a Matrix

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm having trouble calculating the homology groups for a certain space that's hard for me to envision.
Let $X$ be obtained by taking two solid tori and gluing them together along their boundaries using the gluing map corresponding to the matrix $A$:

\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b \\
  c & d 
 \end{pmatrix}
with integer entries. I wish to calculate the homology groups of $X$.

Attempt at solution:
I attempted to use Meyer-Vietoris. Let $U$ be the interior of the second solid torus. This retracts to $S^1$. Let $V$ be the first solid torus as well as a neighbourhood in $U$ so that $V$ contains the boundary of the first solid torus. Then $V$ retracts to a solid torus, which retracts to $S^1$, and the intersection of $U$ and $V$ retracts to a torus. We then get an exact sequence:

$$0\rightarrow H_3(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0 \rightarrow H_2(X)\xrightarrow{\partial_*}\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{(i_*,j_*)}\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{k_*-l_*}H_1(X)\rightarrow0$$
Obviously $H_3(X)$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ by exactness. $H_1(X)\cong^{\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}}/_{im((i_*,j_*))}$, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what that image is, and I have no idea about $\partial_*$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think $(i_{\ast}, j_{\ast})$ is just the matrix $A$.